# How to write a regex to validate a specific URL format?

Tags: regex, url

My URL will look something like this :

> "/eshop/products/SMART+TV+SAMSUNG+UE55H6500SLXXH+3D/productDetail/ger_20295028/"

Where product names can keep changing here 
`SMART+TV+SAMSUNG+UE55H6500SLXXH+3D` and product id here `ger_20295028`. I tried writing a regex which is wrong.

How can I correct it for the above URL?

Regex:

`.*/products/[^/]*?/productDetail/[^/]*?/([^/].*?)/[^/]*?/([^/]*)(/.*?)*$`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You use ? (single character) instead of * (any number) and you also have much more parts at the end than the example you've given. Try something like this

`.*/products/[^/]*/productDetail/[^/]*/`

Comment: Note that this allows for parts of the URL to be empty, eg `/products//productDetail//`

Comment: This regex is working fine but I don't want that part to be empty , how can i do that?

Comment: Change [^/]* to [^/]+ as others have suggested

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on quantifiers (the `?` means once or zero times, you are confusing it with `*`). This regex might work for you:

```
/^.*\/products\/[^\/]+\/productDetail\/[^\/]+\/$/
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/ckbr1e/1).

Comment: No , it did not get match

Comment: @Geek you didn't specify what language you are using to match, but try this: `^.*/products/[^/]+/productDetail/[^/]+/$` instead.

Comment: I am using JAVA

Comment: `"^.*/products/[^/]+/productDetail/[^/]+/$"` works fine in Java.